# PHP - DOMDocument::saveHTML creates weird entities

Tags: php, html, xml, domdocument, simple-html-dom

So I'm pulling xml from an API, and my goal is to save that xhtml as html in a file for users to view.

The problem is, the saved html file get's some new weird entities that it shouldn't have.
Here is an example.

This is what the pulled xhtml snippet looks like:

```
<p>    "At that point
```

And here is what the saved file looks like:

```
<p>&Acirc;&nbsp;&Acirc;&nbsp;&Acirc;&nbsp; "At that point
```

And this is what Chromium sees:

```
<p>Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp;Â&nbsp; "At that point
```

From the xhtml being pulled, to it being saved, it gets processed by a few different classes, so I will simplify all the objects the data gets passed around for simplicity's sake.

```
//curl call is initialized here

$raw = curl_exec($ch);

$simplexml = simplexml_load_string($raw);

$xmlstr = $simplexml->xpath($xpath)->asXML();

$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->formatOutput = true;
$wrapper = $html->createElement("div");
$wrapper->setAttribute("id", "wrapper");
$wrapper = $html->appendChild($wrapper);

$content = DOMDocument::loadHTML($xmlstr, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach($content->firstChild->childNodes as $node)
    $wrapper->appendChild($html->importNode($node, TRUE));

$htmlstr = $html->saveHTML();


$html = new DOMDocument;
$html->formatOutput = true;

$content = DOMDocument::loadHTML($htmlstr, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
foreach($content->childNodes as $node)
    $html->appendChild($html->importNode($node, TRUE));

$html_str = $html->saveHTML();

file_put_contents($content_path, $html_str);
```

Yeah it's a bit complex, but the data gets passed around quite a bit, since it needs to have a lot of stuff added to it.

I just don't understand where those new entities come from. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

I saved the output with simplexml like this:

```
$xmlstr = $simplexml->xpath($xpath)->asXML();
```

This formats the output as XML, but later, when I imported the output to the DOMDoc, I did it with importHTML:

```
$content = DOMDocument::loadHTML($xmlstr, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

I was able to resolve the issue by simply using loadXML instead of loadHTML:

```
$content = DOMDocument::loadXML($xmlstr, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

Now my output is correct:

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; "At that point
```

Although I'm going to write a function to trim() these paragraphs. I don't know why they are provided like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you read or write that with a bad encoding..
First try flush the loaded content to check if the content seems right.

Comment: I just printed out the result from the $simplexml::asXML and the string it printed is identical to the string that the API returned. So the alien entities are created by DOMDocument, not SimpleXML.

Comment: So try to create instance of DOMDocument like this: new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');

Comment: I did it for the wrapper dom and it didn't help. How do I specify encoding in loadHTML()?

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); $dom->loadHTML() :)

Comment: Oh right, lol. Forgot about that. Yeah it didn't help. Same output. I'm only testing it on the first DOMDocument though, not the second, but I'm dumping the output before the second one starts.

Comment: But you pasting into the dom XML right ? So why you not use loadXML ?

Comment: It's actually XHTML. I'm pasting domnodes into the domdocument.

Comment: Ok load it as xml so: remove line with simplexml, and load it into dom as xml with loadXML and from XML generate the HTML.